# Copy all *.txt to *.new.txt but ignore existing *.new.txt files

Tags: bash

I need script for this:

1. Copy all *.txt to *.new.txt
2. When run this script, ignore all *.new.txt files.

What I try:

```
find ~/folder -type f -name "*.txt" ! -name "*.new.txt"
```

how to send this output to

```
cp STDIN *.new.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-exec` to execute a subshell where you copy the file to the modified filename.

```
find ~/folder -type f -name "*.txt" ! -name "*.new.txt" -exec bash -c 'cp "$1" "${1/.txt/.new.txt}"' {} {} \;
```